# Polynomial system of equations over integers

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math, diophantine-equations

I want to solve the system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}
x^4+4y^3+6x^2+4y = -137 \\ 
y^4+4x^3+6y^2+4x = 472
\end{cases}
$$

$x, y \in \Bbb{Z}$.

It most definitely amounts to messing around with algebra and completing the $4$-th powers. Like adding the two equations gives:

$(x+1)^4 + (y+1)^4 = k \in \Bbb{Z}$.

I don't see an obvious way of obtaining another such equation.

But besides simply solving this system I'm also particularly interested in a general way to approach problems like this, preferably avoiding the messy algebra or, if that's not possible, having a general algorithm instead of trying and failing many times to arrive at the appropriate algebraic expression.

Comment: $k = 337$  is prime, therefore at most one way to write it as two squares (in order) namely $81 + 256,$  so $3^4 + 4^4$

Comment: Not that it helps in this case, but you can also subtract the equations, to get $(y-1)^4-(x-1)^4=609$

Comment: $|x+1|,|y+1|$ must be coprime, and $|x+1|,|y+1| \le  \lfloor\sqrt[4] {337} \rfloor = 4$, which doesn't leave too many cases to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we subtract the equations we get to

$$(y−1)^4−(x−1)^4=(y-x)(x+y-2)(x^2+y^2-2x-2y+2)=609=3\times 7\times 29$$

Since $3,7,29$ are primes then we have either:

- $y=x+3$ which solves to $(3,6)$ but not solution of original system
- $y=x-3$ which solves to $(-1,-4)$ but not solution of original system
- $y=x+7$ which solves to $(-1,6)$ but not solution of original system
- $y=x-7$ which solves to $(3,-4)$ also solution of original system
- $y=x\pm 29$ which has no integer solutions

Therefore the only solution is $(3,-4)$

---

Edit:

I though of this refinement today.

Calling $X=x-1$ and $Y=y-1$ then $$Y^4-X^4=(Y^2-X^2)(X^2+Y^2)=(Y-X)(Y+X)(X^2+Y^2)=3\times 7\times 29$$

Since $|X^2-Y^2|<|X^2+Y^2|$ strictly (unless one is $0$ but not possible since $609$ is not a perfect power of $4$) then considering that $3\times 7<29$ the only possibility is $X^2+Y^2=29$.

Whose decomposition is immediate as $29=25+4$ and $X,Y\in\{\pm 2\ ;\ \pm 5\}$

Among these only $X=\pm 2,Y=\pm 5$ gives $+3,+7$ or $-3,-7$ as sum and difference.

After testing in original equation in $x,y$ only $(3,-4)$ susbsists.

Comment: subtract what equations and how did you get to second equality?

Comment: $a^4-b^4=(a^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2)=(a-b)(a+b)(a^2+b^2)$

Comment: How did you find (y−1)^4−(x−1)^4

Comment: Coefficients are $1,4,6,4,1$ with some $-$ signs when subtracting, indicative of $(x-1)^4$

Answer (score 6):

Taking the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) over the complex numbers we obtain that either $(x,y)=(3,-4)$, or that $x$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial of degree $15$, having no rational root. So $x=3,y=-4$ is the only integral solution.

Added: The resultant equation is the following:
$$
(x-3)(x^{15} + 3x^{14} + 33x^{13} + 99x^{12} + 1061x^{11} + 2287x^{10} + 17589x^9 + 57503x^8
 + 453731x^7 + 1121833x^6 + 291875x^5 - 826007x^4 + 33699383x^3 + 776909093x^2
 + 2564361287x + 8370351445)=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you. I have thought of resultants, but I also would like to find a more or less elementary approach. I also think some form of diagonalization can be applicable to these polynomials in order to get the sum of powers for a general case.